# Exclude posts from featuring

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories

I'm trying to hide posts from a specific category from being featured. Currently, the section shows featured posts from all categories. I need to exclude posts from a category (with category name not by id).

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_key'       => 'meta-checkbox',
    'meta_value'     => 'yes',
    );
$featured = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @MarkKaplun "I need to exclude posts from a specific category"

Comment: that is a statement, not a question :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Excluding specific categories from WP_Query**

This is in the codex. You can exlclude specific categories from WP_Query. Where array(2, 6) are IDs for categories to be excluded in this example.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

See the codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

**NOTE: If you are trying to exclude category by the name of category**

First you would do this to find the category ID by providing category name.

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID( 'My Category' );
```

then add the returned `$category_id` in your WP Query arguments it would look like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( $category_id ) ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add `'exclude'          => '',` in your args array

or just provide the category id ,comma separated like below

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'meta-checkbox',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
'category'         => '2,3,4,5,6,7,8',
    );
```

See this link :https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: I was using 'cat' instead of 'category'. Thanks @vanurag

Comment: Glad that it worked !!!

Comment: this code is including, not excluding :(

Comment: Sorry. not worked :( @vanurag . I refreshed live version website instead of localhost.

Comment: To exclude any category you just need to put `minus (-)` with category ID. For example in your code line `'category'         => '2,3,4,5,6,7,8',`. Suppose you need to exclude 2 and 3 ID then put minus with them like this `'category'         => '-2,-3,4,5,6,7,8',`. Then 2 and 3 ID will get removed. And I use `cat` for category instead of `category`. But if its working fine for you then ok. You can update your answer with that solution :)